# Refactoring! How to Re-Use a Variable in Database Query to retrieve data in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, refactoring

I am trying to **refactor** the code in my rails API which sends analytics data for charts (***it is currently working***). As I have the same code carried out on 1. Bookmarks, 2. Journals, 3. Goals and it isn't very dry.

I am trying to create 1 database query (using PostgreSQL) that can receive the type (bookmark, goal, journal) as a parameter... I have tried using [:type] and hard coding "type" where bookmark used to go for example...

Existing (working) code that I want to refactor:

```
class AnalyticsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user

  def entries_by_date
    bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks.group_by_day(
      :created_at,
      format: '%Y-%m-%d',
      range: 4.weeks.ago.midnight..Time.zone.now
    ).count
    journals = current_user.journals.group_by_day(
      :created_at,
      format: '%Y-%m-%d',
      range: 4.weeks.ago.midnight..Time.zone.now
    ).count
    goals = current_user.goals.group_by_day(
      :created_at,
      format: '%Y-%m-%d',
      range: 4.weeks.ago.midnight..Time.zone.now
    ).count

    entries_array = []
    entries_array.push(@bookmarks)
    entries_array.push(goals)
    entries_array.push(journals)

    total_entries_by_date = entries_array.inject { |memo, el| memo.merge(el) { |_k, old_v, new_v| old_v + new_v } }

    render json: {
      total_entries_by_date: total_entries_by_date,
      bookmarks: bookmarks,
      goals: goals,
      journals: journals
    }
  end
end
```

I have tried this:

```
.... 

  def entries_by_date
    def fetch_activity(type)
      current_user[:type].group_by_day(
        :created_at,
        format: '%Y-%m-%d',
        range: 4.weeks.ago.midnight..Time.zone.now
      ).count
    end

    @bookmarks = fetch_activity(bookmarks)
    @goals = fetch_activity(goals)
    @journals = fetch_activity(journals) 


... (cont'd)
```

I have tried current_user.type... >> undefined local variable or method `bookmarks

I have tried current_user.[:type]... >> "Syntax error, unknown ["

I have tried current_user[:type]... >> NameError (undefined local variable or method `bookmarks'

I have tried current_user.%{type}... &  current_user.#{type}... &  current_user.${type}

Any guidance would be much appreciated :) I'm fairly new to the Ruby on Rails world and looking forward to seeing my code a little drier once I have a better understanding of how to re-use the variables being passed into a database query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close to the solution. Just use [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send) and pass the name of the method you want to call as a string or symbol.

```
def entries_by_date
  @bookmarks = fetch_activity(:bookmarks)
  @goals = fetch_activity(:goals)
  @journals = fetch_activity(:journals) 

  # ...
end

private

def fetch_activity(type)
  current_user.public_send(type).group_by_day(
    :created_at,
    format: '%Y-%m-%d',
    range: 4.weeks.ago.midnight..Time.zone.now
  ).count
end

@bookmarks = fetch_activity(bookmarks)
@goals = fetch_activity(goals)
@journals = fetch_activity(journals)
```

Comment: Hi Spickermann, thank you so much! I was oh so close but oh so far :) I'm going to do some research now on the public_send syntax. Appreciate you taking the time :) this was my first ever Stack Overflow question

Answer (score 4):

To improve a bit on Spickerman's answer - you should consider extracting the buisness logic from the controller and place it in the model where it belongs:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Gets a single activity 
  def fetch_activity(type)
    public_send(type).group_by_day(
      :created_at,
      format: '%Y-%m-%d',
      range: 4.weeks.ago.midnight..Time.zone.now
    ).count
  end

  # Gets a hash containing the counts of the users activities and total 
  def fetch_activities(*types)
    types.each_with_object({}) do |key, hash|
      hash[key] = fetch_activity(key)
    end.then do |hash|
      hash.merge(total_entries_by_date: hash.values.sum)
    end
  end
  # ... 
end
```

Models are much easier to test than controllers since you can just set it up and call the method right on the object instead of going though HTTP and parsing the response - which is a key reason why your controllers should be as skinny as possible:

```
class AnalyticsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user

  def entries_by_date
    render json: current_user.fetch_activities(:bookmarks, :goals, :journals)
  end
end
```

Comment: yes and writing tests before starting any refactoring would be a great step for refactoring, in case there wasn't any.

Comment: Thank you @max! I had just read recently about the concept of skinny controllers and 'fat' models. I'm going to take some time to refactor my controllers in this way too. Incredibly useful thank you:)

Comment: No problem. `Object#then/yeild_self` was introduced in Ruby 2.6 so you might need to adjust the code slightly to make it run in older versions.